# PowerShell mandatory parameter depends on another parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, dependencies, registry, flags

I have a PowerShell function which changes the registry key values. Code:

```
param(
    [Parameter()] [switch]$CreateNewChild,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$PropertyType
)
```

It has a parameter, "CreateNewChild", and if that flag is set, the function will create the key property, even if it wasn't found. The parameter "PropertyType" must be mandatory, but only if "CreateNewChild" flag has been set.

The question is, how do I make a parameter mandatory, but only if another parameter has been specified?

OK, I've been playing around with it. And this does work:

```
param(
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName="one")]
  [switch]$DoNotCreateNewChild,

  [string]$KeyPath,

  [string]$Name,

  [string]$NewValue,

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName="two")]
  [switch]$CreateNewChild,

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName="two",Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$PropertyType
)
```

However, this means that $KeyPath, $Name and $NewValue are not mandatory any more. Setting "one" parameter set to mandatory breaks the code (*"parameter set cannot be resolved"* error). These parameter sets are confusing. I'm sure there is a way, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could group those parameters by defining a parameter set to accomplish this.

```powershell
param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='One')][switch]$CreateNewChild,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='One',Mandatory=$true)][string]$PropertyType
)
```

Reference:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-v2-parametersets

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands.aspx

--- Update ---

Here's a snippet that mimics the functionality you're looking for. The "Extra" parameter set will not be processed unless the -Favorite switch is called.

```powershell
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName='None')] 
param( 
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Age, 
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Sex, 
    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Location,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Extra',Mandatory=$false)][switch]$Favorite,      
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Extra',Mandatory=$true)][string]$FavoriteCar
)

$ParamSetName = $PsCmdLet.ParameterSetName
    
Write-Output "Age: $age"
Write-Output "Sex: $sex"
Write-Output "Location: $Location"
Write-Output "Favorite: $Favorite"
Write-Output "Favorite Car: $FavoriteCar"
Write-Output "ParamSetName: $ParamSetName"
```

Comment: I've tried this, here is the code:
`param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$KeyPath,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$NewValue,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="One")][switch]$CreateNewChild,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="One",Mandatory=$true)] [string]$PropertyType
    )
`However, this doesn't work. When trying to execute the following:
`Set-RegistryKeyPropertyValue -KeyPath $path -Name $name -NewValue 0`
It asks me to supply the value for $PropertyType, as it's mandatory

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I have added a better example to the answer above. :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!
p.s. The one option that I haven't tried to make "$Favorite" mandatory=$false, I thought it was false by default. This parameter set logic is weird...

Comment: You're welcome. Dynamic parameters, as walid2mi suggests, are another option. I'd suggest reading this article to understand more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878334(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Good article, thanks! And it's not in French as the thread that walid2mi posted =)

Comment: What will happen if pass `-Favorite:$false`? Will `FavoriteCar` still be mandatory? (I expect it should not be mandatory in this case.)

Comment: Also I don't think this prevents someone from passing `PropertyType` and not passing `CreateNewChild`

Comment: If you're looking for the blogs linked above, I think these are the new locations:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-v2-parametersets/



https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/

Answer (score -5):

You can also use a dynamic parameter:

*[New way to create a dynamic parameter](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1271564/general-developpement/programmation-systeme/windows/scripts-batch/astuce-traduire-directives-parametres-dynamiques/)*

Comment: Just providing a link to a foreign language forum isn't helpful at all. Please provide an example that would solve to described problem.

Comment: This is a good answer better links are available (http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters#-47

Comment: Providing a link is not an answer. You should provide answer in here at least some summary and provide link for OP if he wants to know more, preferably avoiding foreign languages. Bare in mind that people will get here after several years and provided link might be dead by that time